# Trying to get RHS column to stay fixed while LHS is scrollable

Tags: html, css

I've got a stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/tailwindcss-6th36s?file=index.html

I'd like the LHS to contain many blocks and to be scrollable according to the page scroll (not scrollable in its own div, if that makes sense). I also want the RHS to remain fixed so that the column doesn't move while the left side scrolls.

I've tried applying sticky here, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've added a threshold via "top" and applied "overflow: visible" to the parent but it hasn't helped.

Indeed is a good example of the behaviour I'd like - https://uk.indeed.com/Web3-jobs-in-United-Kingdom?vjk=d5471bfad907f0dd

This is using tailwind also.

```
HTML
<div id="app">
      <div class="container-job-board overflow-auto">
        <div class="w-full flex flex-row h-full overflow-visible">
          <div class="w-full job-list">
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">
              These should be able to scroll with the page
            </div>
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">Block</div>
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">Block</div>
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">Block</div>
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">Block</div>
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">Block</div>
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">Block</div>
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">Block</div>
            <div class="w-full h-32 border">Block</div>
          </div>
          <div class="w-spacer"></div>
          <div class="w-full border bg-white rounded-md rhs">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p>This side should stay fixed</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

CSS
.w-spacer {
  width: 10%;
}

.job-list > * {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.job-list > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.rhs {
  height: calc(100vh - 4.5rem);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your .rhs class have a fixed position, you will have to play around with what width you want for each side.

https://tailwindcss-ugphg9.stackblitz.io

Comment: Seems like a bit of a hacky fix tbh, and it makes alignment way more difficult. Surely there's a way to do this using a flexbox layout or something?